# Is there a way to fix which update version is shown in Pokémon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

I recently got a new phone and switch from Android to iPhone. After I configured my phone, the first app I installed was Pokémon Go. The current version for iPhone is 1.29.1, which the app store reflects correctly.

[image]

I went into the settings to turn off music/sounds effects, but I noticed that it is displaying the latest version Android, being 0.59.1.

[image]

Is there a way I can fix this to display the correct update version?

Comment: Report a Critical Issue.  But in all seriousness, this is probably not wrong.  Niantic may have an internal version number that's embedded in the game that happens to be the same as the Android version.  Apple may have some sort of rule stating how version numbers must be represented on their store. All of this is just my guess though.

Comment: The latest Android version is now 0.59.2, with no corresponding iOS version.  Timmy Jim is correct though.  The iOS version numbering is to satisfy Apple's requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After seeing @TimmyJim's comment and checking my own app, I realized that this isn't due to you switching phones. The number displayed in the iOS version of the app displays the Android version number. I have been using iPhones since 2010 and mine displays the same version as yours.

[image: android version number on iOS]

Thus, the app displaying the Android version number appears to be the "correct" behavior, so there is not a way to fix this.

Comment: That makes sense. Migrating from Android, I thought it was cached or something of the sort